# Pattern mining from a genomic sequence

Tags: r, python, bash, perl, shell

I need to find the following pattern from a genomic sequence

```
TTCGB-N15-TTCGB
B represents C, G, or T
N15 represents A, T, G or C and these four base combination should have the length of 15 bases.
```

To do the same, I tried `grep` command, but I could not specify `B` and `N15` in the `grep` command line. Therefore, please help me to find the same.

For example, I have a nucleotide sequences as follows

```
>ATGCTTATTGCCCATTTCGTGCATGCATATGCGCATTCGCGATCGATTAGGGATAT
```

Expected outcome,

> TTCGTGCATGCATATGCGCATTCGC

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please update your question to clarify that N15 represents A, T, G or C for *exactly* 15 bases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo ">ATGCTTATTGCCCATTTCGTGCATGCATATGCGCATTCGCGATCGATTAGGGATAT" | grep -oP  'TTCG[CGT][ATGC]{1,15}TTCG[CGT]'
```

- `[CGT]` looks for one occurrence of one of the three.
- `[ATGC]{1,15}` looks for "up to 15 letter long" combinations of the four bases.

Moreover, `-P` makes your regex call `Perl-like` and is required to make this regex work. Different regex flavors behave (slightly) differently.

Comment: Dear @haci,                                                                                                                       I have followed your command line for the test data (I had given in the example section of my question), which gives proper result. But when I tried the same with my genome file with the following command, `echo $(<org15.fasta) | grep -oP  'TTCG[CGT][ATGC]{1,15}TTCG[CGT]'` and I am getting output as follows,   `TTCGCCGCGGCGACGTTTTCGC
TTCGCATTCGG
TTCGCCACCTTGTTCGG
TTCGGCTTTCGC
TTCGTGGCCTTCGG
TTCGGCTTCTTCGT
TTCGTCAAGGACCCGATTTCGG
TTCGCATCTTCGC
`

Comment: The thing is that, the script mining TTCGB.....TTCGB, but fails to fulfil the length N15 criteria. kindly help me to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: What is your "N15 criteria" though? `[ATGC]{1,15}` looks for **up to** 15 repetitions of the four bases as you specified in your question. And as far as I can see in the output you get, this is what you are getting, 2 `TTCGB` stretches are connected by up to 15 bases.

Comment: N15 usually means exactly 15 of any nucleotides. So use [ACGTN]{15} . Also, -i flag for grep may need to be added if some of the sequence is lower case, for example repeat masked.

Comment: @haci N15 means any of the 4 bases, but N15 length should be 15. exactly, The output should be like this, `TTCGB-ATGCTAGCATGATAG-TTCGB`. The output sequence should have `TTCGB` at both ends, at the same time in between `TTCGB` 15 bases also should be there. That 15 bases can be the combination of any of the four bases, but it should have 15 bases. Sorry, if my question is not clear.

Comment: OK, then just change `[ATGC]{1,15}` to `[ATGC]{15}` as Timur Shtatland suggested. The reason for `[ATGC]{1,15}` was your phrase in the question: "N represents A, T, G or C up to 15 bases".

Comment: @haci I did it `echo $(<org15.fasta) | grep -oP 'TTCG[CGT][ATGCN]{15}TTCG[CGT]'`. It works, thank you so much @haci and @Timur Shtatland.